# HTML Formatting not working in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a symfony 2 form in back-end where I have rich text field with tiny mce editor. The data type of this field is varchar in database table.

When I prints its content on front side then formatting does not work. It shows plain text rather than html formatted content.

How it prints:

```
< p >< strong >Hello< /strong >< /p >
```

How it should print:

**Hello**

Any solution?

Comment: how do you print the variable in your twig file?

Comment: @javad i print it like this {{ content }}

Comment: Check the answer and use the `raw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print a variable which contains HTML characters, as code string use `escape` (which is default in Symfony)

```
{{ content|escape }}
```

To print a variable which contains HTML characters, as a none code string use `raw`

```
{{ content|raw }}
```